# what is the probability that the first box is empty?

Tags: combinatorics

If we choose a box for each ball uniformly from all possible boxes, and do this independently for each ball, what is the probability that the first box is empty?

So for this problem, this is asking for the first box as being empty.

Let there be m boxes and n indistinguishable balls.  so for the first box to be empty we have $\binom{m+n-2}{n}$ ways of distributing the balls such that first box is empty.

and we have $m^n$ total ways of drawing the balls.

so is this $\binom{m+n-2}{n}$ / $m^n$ ?

i'm not sure if we are drawing with replacement or not?

or should we say that $(\frac{m-1}{m})^n$ since we can fix the first as empty, and then toss the balls n times?

Comment: If it was a combinatorics question, yes, $\binom{m+n-2}{n}$ would be the number of distinct ways to distribute $n$ balls into $m$ boxes so the first box is empty. Does not work for probability. Also in your first answer, you have numerator using Stars and Bars and denominator assuming each ball is independently put into $m$ boxes.

Comment: we can not use the numerator 'stars/bars' approach for probability here because each draw does not have equal probability correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You have to be always careful whether the question is about combinations or probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second answer is correct. Given this is a probability question, please do not apply Stars and Bars method as all sequences in Stars and Bars are not equally probable.

Number of ways to put each ball in $m$ boxes = $m$

Number of ways to put $n$ balls in $m$ boxes = $m^n$

Number of ways to put $n$ balls in $(m-1)$ boxes = $(m-1)^n$

So the probability that the first box is empty $ \displaystyle = \frac {(m-1)^n}{m^n}$